# Gradle delete task not working as expected

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to delete a temporary file created in my project. I used the following build file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply from: 'https://github.com/valkolovos/gradle_cobertura/raw/master/repo/gradle_cobertura/gradle_cobertura/1.0/coberturainit.gradle'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: "4.+" 
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task deleteStuff(type: Delete) {
    delete 'testfile.txt'
}

defaultTasks 'cobertura'
```

But the testfile.txt is not getting deleted.Anything i am missing?

Comment: I added " deleteStuff" task to  defaultTasks 'cobertura','deleteStuff'
and it worked.

Comment: Otherwise you could run explicitly the `deleteStuff` task with `gradle deleteStuff`.